# Finder crashes whenever I try and open certain directory

Tags: finder, mojave, crash

I'm running Mojave 10.14.6 and I have a strange issue whenever I try to open a particular directory in Finder, or even in Terminal (using `open .` while `pwd`).

Attempting to open the directory causes Finder to completely crash and I cannot open a window of the directory at all, although I can `cd` into it and see the files using `ls` in Terminal.

The folder is `/Library/Preferenes/app_config` and it's created by one of my Scientific CAD applications.

The errors I get when I try to open it are:

```
> Nov  6 21:26:54 Crapple Finder[2776]: assertion failed: 18G103:
> libxpc.dylib + 90677 [7DEE2300-6D8E-3C00-9C63-E3E80D56B0C4]: 0x89
> 
> Nov  6 21:26:54 Crapple com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]
> (com.apple.imfoundation.IMRemoteURLConnectionAgent): Unknown key for
> integer: _DirtyJetsamMemoryLimit
> 
> Nov  6 21:26:54 Crapple com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]
> (com.adobe.accmac.ACCFinderSync.A26C65A3-1B74-476F-9620-1D52DB676221[2781]):
> Caller wanted oneshot behavior for pre-existing instance: caller =
> Finder
> 
> Nov  6 21:26:55 Crapple Finder[2776]: objc[2776]: Class
> FIFinderSyncExtensionHost is implemented in both
> /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder
> (0x107f1e750) and
> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FileProvider.framework/OverrideBundles/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride.bundle/Contents/MacOS/FinderSyncCollaborationFileProviderOverride
> (0x1091eaf50). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
> 
> Nov  6 21:26:59 Crapple com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]
> (com.apple.quicklook[2782]): Endpoint has been activated through
> legacy launch(3) APIs. Please switch to XPC or bootstrap_check_in():
> com.apple.quicklook
> 
> Nov  6 21:27:12 Crapple VTEncoderXPCService[761]: DEPRECATED USE in
> libdispatch client: Changing the target of a source after it has been
> activated; set a breakpoint on _dispatch_bug_deprecated to debug
```

Any hints on how to fix this annoying problem would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: Can you try ```sudo chmod 777 directoryname```. This will give everyone read, write, and execute permissions on the directory. If the issue stops after this, then it's an issue with your file permissions.

Comment: @Todd: Thanks, but it still crashes, and folders in that particular directory shouldn't have those permissions most likely.

Comment: Can you try running First Aid in Disk Utility? This step will make sure that this isn’t corruption.

Comment: Googling for com.adobe.accmac.ACCFinderSync https://community.adobe.com/t5/coding-corner/what-is-the-xcode-error-quot-plugin-com-adobe-accmac-accfindersync-invalidated-quot/td-p/7964655?page=1 suggests disabling Adobe plugin https://community.adobe.com/t5/coding-corner/what-is-the-xcode-error-quot-plugin-com-adobe-accmac-accfindersync-invalidated-quot/td-p/7964655?page=1

Comment: @Todd: See next comment.

Comment: @mmmmmm: I took both advices (yours and Todd's)... repaired disk permissions and disabled the Adobe extension. After doing so the behavior was the same until I rebooted. I can now open that directory in Finder, so hopefully it stays working now, thanks! Also it doesn't appear the latest Disk Utility repairs permissions? I ended up doing it manually, so if there's a way with Disk Utility or what not let me know.

Comment: Repairing permissions n e very really fixed anything